# How to save image to album if canvas same origin flag is dirty

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, firefox-os

I am facing a difficult situation here. I am building an Open Web App that display Tweets. If any of these tweets contains an URL to an image, we display the image with an image tag. I want to give the user the option to save this image to his album or share it using the share web activity.

All web activities that work on image expect a blob to work. We can't simply pass a URL to it. I can't build a blob from a remote image because as soon as I try using a drawImage canvas call to blit that image into the canvas I get an security error on the canvas due to the image not coming from the same origin as the app.

This "security" prevents all types of fiddling with remote images such as saving it to disk or using web activities.

I understand this is a part of the spec but I don't really understand the purpose. Its just images after all and if I am scripting the save of a remote image there is a chance that I know what I am doing but then again I was not a part of the w3c group that decided about that spec and those folks are much smarter than I am so I am probably overseeing something...

Anyway, lets summarize: "How do I go from an img tag with its source pointing at a remote location which is not the same as the Open Web App to a blob that I can use with web activities?"

Thanks

Comment: The "security" does not prevent access when you deliver content from the same site that's serving the app.  The workaround is to upload the user's images to your website and serve them back for use in their albums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then [Share](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Web_Activities) activity does support using a URL.  The Boilerplate app has an [example of this](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App/blob/gh-pages/js/webapp.js#l141).  If you do not mind your app being privileged (Which requires a thorough review by the marketplace) you can try using a [systemXHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).  The code will look similar to:

```
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({
            mozSystem: true
        });
        xhr.open("GET", "url to image", true);
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = function () {
            //sample activity - use any activity that requires blob
            var activity = new MozActivity({
            name: "open",
            data: {
                type: "image/png",
                blob: this.response,
            },
            });
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            alert("Error with System XHR");
        };
        xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason! I might go with the xhr call, the app is already privileged.

Answer (score 2):

This is not "security", this is **Security**. I understand your frustration, but what you want to do is inherently unsafe, just like giving web apps access to local files. It does not matter that YOU could find it useful. So could the bad guys.

Loading images **bypasses same origin policy**. This means that ANY web application can load ANY image from ANY other application that the browser's user is currently logged in to: email attachments (including renditions of PDFs), private galleries on Facebook, anything at all. This does not lead serious attacks just because "accessing" the image this way gives very little: you can force the browser to load the image, but you cannot read it back or send it back to your server. Unrestricted access to canvas would break this last line of defense: attackers could load your secret images, render them to canvas and read back the data.

It's quite similar to how iframe security works: since any web application can load any other application into an iframe, cross origin iframes are impossible to access from outside, you cannot read back any data from them.

Comment: I understand it better now. I always considered the application running in an isolated context so I never though about a "tab" loading stuff from some other logged app. Thanks for pointing that.